# Need equation to find break-even point for products with fixed costs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

This is probably highschool-level stuff, but I haven't been in highschool for a long time...

Anyway, I have a product with known costs for a single production run. It will be sold by someone making 25% commission. In addition to the commission, we will have to pay payroll taxes amounting to 9% of the commission paid.

I need to figure out how many dollars' worth of products need to be sold in order to break even on the combined total of the product run, the commission to that point, and the payroll tax to that point.

In plain English, here's the equation I'm working with:

```
$ProductionRun + ($TotalSales * 25%) + ($TotalCommission * 9%) = $TotalCosts
```

However, what I'm after is the dollar amount where TotalSales matches TotalCosts.

How would one go about this?

Comment: Why do you think that they don´t match? Do you make any profit?

Comment: We're in pre-production. I need to calculate the break-even point for projections.

Comment: Do the answers capture the meaning of the question?

Comment: Yes, now I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to get it into my Excel spreadsheet. :)

Comment: In the first cell of column A (A1) you insert 0. Then at the next row (A2) you insert the formula $\text{=$A$1+1}$. *Then you hover the mouse cursor over a small square at the lower right-hand corner of the cell, which is called the Fill handle. As you do this, the cursor will change to a thick black cross.
Hold and drag the fill handle down the column over the cells where you want to copy the formula*. This can be done as well for the next column. First you input in cell B1 the formula  $\text{=A1/(1-0.2725)}$. Then you copy the formula in the same way as for the column A.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation. I actually worked out a different method, using the following formula, where each of the variables is a named reference for a cell containing the data in question:

=SUM(ProductionCosts / (1 - ((CommissionRate * WithholdingsRate) + CommissionRate)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s$ is sales and $p$ is production cost, your commission is $0.25s$ and your payroll tax is $0.09 \cdot 0.25s=0.0225s$.  The total costs are then $p+0.2725s$ and you break even when this is $s$.  You need
$$p+0.2725s=s\\s=\frac p{1-0.2725}\approx 1.3746p$$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, here's how I'd solve the problem

Since commission is 25% of sales, we multiply total sales by 0.25. Moreover, due to taxes, we multiply the commission by 1.09

So:

$$\textrm{Production_Costs} + \textrm{Total_Sales}\cdot0.25\cdot1.09=\textrm{Total_Sales}$$
$$\textrm{Production_Costs} = 0.7275*\textrm{Total_Sales}$$

Hence, sales need to be $\frac 1 {0.7275} \cdot100\%-100\%=37.457\%$ higher than production costs.